# how to compare unix timestamp in Redis?

Tags: redis

Suppose i have a unix timestamp value that stored in a key

```
> SET timer 1465057009
```

Is there command to compare the timestamp with current timestamp?

```
> IS_BEFORE_NOW(timer)
1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. But you can use a simple lua script to achieve it. For that you need to use redis command time which will return you the server's time.

```
local timer=redis.call("get","timer")
if timer > redis.call("time")[1] then
    return true
end
return false
```